# Why dot notation failed in my property access?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning from the book: Javascript the good parts. And I came across the following code augmenting function definitions.

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func){
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

However, if I replace `this.prototype[name]` with `this.prototype.name` there is an error from Firebug, and I was wondering where is the mistake? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to access the property `name` from `this.prototype`, where name is a variable. If you used dot notation it would try to look up the literal string `'name'` as a property of the `Function.prototype` and of course cant find it. Use `[name]` if the property name is a variable.

Comment: Thank you Joe. What if I insist on using dot?

Comment: you can't, if the property name is a variable, the only way to access it would be to use [name]

Answer (score 2):

`this.prototype.name` is equivalent to `this.prototype["name"]` not `this.prototype[name]`.

Comment: Actually, your answer does not explain why the error takes place.

Answer (score 1):

In the dot case, name is treated literally, and it is not defined in your case. On the contrary, the name in the brackets are treated as a reference to a string Object.